# How can I save a given project as template in Visual Studio 2022 community

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, visual-studio-2022

I have a C# Razor pages app in a tabbed container page. I want to save this project as a template. How do I go about doing that in Visual Studio 2022 Community edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Microsoft docs [Create project templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2022)

On the last page, provided a meaningful name for the template and if possible an image.

Comment: I was on chatGPT , it was not aware of what you pointed. Thanks